# Arabic page under smartphone are out of window

Tags: css, google-chrome, arabic

Only for arabic and farsi version, only width Chrome (android or desktop but with smartphone simulation on), the web page are floating far away to the right... It's seems to have a white page, but the page is on the right. In english or french... no problem !

An idea ? An issue with the css ?

if EN : http://dev.worldcoalition.org
in arabic : http://dev.worldcoalition.org/ar/

thnaks a lot !